# private type declaration is throwing error?

Tags: constants, private, record, ada

private type declaration is throwing error?my code is below please help me to fix it
error is=>  "missing full declaration of private type t"

spec file

```
 package rec is
 type t is private;
 give_public_acess:Constant t;
private
   type int_array is array(1..5)of integer;
   type t_type is record
     max:integer:=0;
     data:int_array;
  end record;
  give_public_acess:constant t_type:=(0,(others=>1)); --error is here adacore site says these is good but throwing error?
  end rec;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile your code I get **2** error messages:

```
rec.ads:2:07: missing full declaration for private type "t"
rec.ads:10:03: type does not match declaration at line 3
```

These are both because you call the type `t` in the public part and `t_type` in the private part. The first means exactly what it says; the second is because in the public part you say

```
give_public_acess:Constant t;
```

and in the private part

```
give_public_acess:constant t_type
```

I suggest you try compiling with `-gnatl` (full listing): this intersperses error messages with the code, so you get

```
 1. package rec is
 2.  type t is private;
          |
    >>> missing full declaration for private type "t"

 3.  give_public_acess:Constant t;
 4. private
 5.    type int_array is array(1..5)of integer;
 6.    type t_type is record
 7.      max:integer:=0;
 8.      data:int_array;
 9.   end record;
10.   give_public_acess:constant t_type:=(0,(others=>1)); --error is here adacore site says these is good but throwing error?
      |
    >>> type does not match declaration at line 3

11.   end rec;
```